# Issue with Requests Library - Unable to Fetch API Data

Tags: python

I'm currently grappling with an issue in my Python project that involves utilizing the requests library to fetch data from an API. Despite structuring the code as per the library's documentation, I'm unable to retrieve the expected data. The code snippet initiates a GET request to the API endpoint, represented by the URL 'https://api.example.com/data', and attempts to process the response using print(response. text). However, the response. text is consistently empty, indicating a failure in fetching the data.

No error messages are displayed, complicating the troubleshooting process. I've rigorously verified the correctness of the API endpoint, ensuring it's operational by successfully testing it using cURL. Additionally, I meticulously reviewed the documentation for the requests library but found no solution to the problem.

My development environment consists of Python version 3.8.5 and the Requests library version 2.26.0. The anticipated outcome is for response. text to contain the data fetched from the API. Regrettably, this is not the case, and I'm seeking guidance or insights from the community to identify and resolve the root cause of this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please immediately before your `print(response. text)` following lines `print(response.status_code)` and `print(response.headers)` run your code once again and add what was unveiled to your question

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)